# PHP crypt() sha-512 hash length

Tags: php, encryption, hash

Using PHP crypt() and the $6$ indicator for sha-512, I get a hash that is   118 characters long using the following code:

```
$salt= '$6$rounds=2500$'.substr( md5(uniqid(rand(),true)), 0,22)."$";
$hash=crypt($pass,$salt);
```

Seems like a weird number, but can I assume that number will be consistent so I can use CHAR() in the database instead of VARCHAR()?

Comment: Please read the manual before doing anything https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html *"The CHAR and VARCHAR types are similar, but differ in the way they are "* - Plus, why not use `password_hash()` instead? Any particular reason for using sha?

Comment: sadly password_hash is not supported below PHP 5.5. Host uses 5.4, though currently upgrading to 5.5.

Comment: *Easy*. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use CHAR() because the hash length should generally be that same for every string you hash. VARCHAR() is better suited for strings where you really don't know the length such as for an email address.

It would be inefficient to store, for example, short 5 character strings in a CHAR(200) because of the empty space you'll be reserving but if all the strings are generally the same length then it becomes worth while to use a CHAR() of the appropriate length.

VARCHAR() stores the string and the length of the string, this makes it more efficient at storing strings where the length of each sting in inconsistent.